# How well does the 5 second test/blink test work on mobile?

Tags: usability, website-design, mobile

If you have not heard of the 5 second test before please see the following two articles (below each quote).

> Five seconds may seem like a short time, but in fact it is more than
>   enough  time for a website visitor to determine if there is enough
>   quality in your website to stay, or to leave potentially never to
>   return.
>   [UIE article](http://www.usefulusability.com/5-second-test/)
>
> Give users five seconds to look at an image or page-design and you get
>   instant feedback on salient elements or problems in a design. If users
>   can't find their way or orient to your design immediately, then this
>   can be an early indication the design needs improving. [MeasuringU
>   article](http://www.measuringu.com/five-second-tests.php)

My questions are:

- Has anyone tried it?
- How effective is it?
- What would you use to try it?

Any other thoughts on the 5 second test in general or on mobile is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I like 5 sec tests but You can't get so much from 5 second test. it is more get OK test type and can be named as guerrilla kind of test.  Trustworthy , company domain, service type can be questioned within 5 sec test.

Brand engagement and recalling name can also part of this test. It can be also used when you choose an image, logo or icon.

5 sec test can be also used for creating connotation map for search engines. the question example is "you are going to buy a baby fooding for your 6 month old baby. how are you going to search?"

The test has a scientific base in cognitive science.

> The official normative ratings for the IAPS pictures were obtained from a sample of 100 college students (50 women, 50 men, presumably predominantly US-American) who each rated 16 sets of 60 pictures. The rating was carried out in groups using paper-and-pencil versions of the SAMs. Pictures were presented for **6 seconds each**; 15 seconds were given to rate the picture. /dominance. Average valence, arousal and dominance ratings are available for the overall sample, men, and women.
>
> Normative ratings were also obtained from children ages 7–9 years, 10-12, and 13-14. The rating procedure for children was mildly adapted; among other modifications, **children were tested in classrooms, given instructions in a more child-friendly language, and they were allotted 20 seconds to rate each picture instead of 15**.

Comment: How would I find out more about the 5 second test's relevance in cognitive science?

Comment: @razzer-bake Many studies that use International Affective Picture System - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Affective_Picture_System editing answer according to this.

Answer (score 0):

The 5 second test is essentially evaluating the quality and appropriateness of the visual/graphic design. As such, it could really be applied to most any visually designed piece...be it a brochure, desktop web site, or a mobile app.